# ArcGIS Near analysis ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am attempting to iterate through one shapefile to find the nearest point in another shapefile. I am getting the following error when I attempt to use the Near tool on an iterated row.

[image: Model]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Highly suspected that you have some issues with paths and their naming.

Check for the below measure:

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012177

Also, try the GP tool and cross-validate.